# Multiple conditions on select query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a select statement and I wish to calculate the cubic volume based on other values within the table. However I want to check that neither pr.Length_mm or pr.Width_mm or pr.Height_mm are NULL prior. I've looked at CASE statements, however it only seems to evaluate one column at a time.

```
SELECT 
      sa.OrderName,
      sa.OrderType,
      pr.Volume_UOM
 ,pr.Length_mm*pr.Width_mm*pr.Height_mm AS Volume_Cubic
 ,pr.Length_mm*pr.Width_mm AS Volume_Floor
 ,pr.Length_mm
 ,pr.Height_mm
 ,pr.Width_mm
FROM CostToServe_MCB.staging.Sale sa
LEFT JOIN staging.Product pr
ON sa.ID = pr.ID
```

Comment: Why are you left joining here? `LEFT JOIN`-ing and then using `IS NOT NULL` on the right hand table seems somewhat pointless. All of the rows preserved by using left join rather than inner will have `NULL` in all `pr` columns.

Comment: @MartinSmith I think you're right, but couldn't you put the condition in the join? Check my updated answer.

Comment: This is a subset of the full query. There are other columns which I need to bring in which may not be part of the right table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT pr.Volume_UOM
 ,pr.Length_mm*pr.Width_mm*pr.Height_mm AS Volume_Cubic
 ,pr.Length_mm*pr.Width_mm AS Volume_Floor
 ,pr.Length_mm
 ,pr.Height_mm
 ,pr.Width_mm
FROM CostToServe_MCB.staging.Sale sa
LEFT JOIN staging.Product pr
ON sa.ID = pr.ID
and pr.Length_mm is not null
and pr.Width_mm is not null
and pr.Height_mm is not null
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT pr.Volume_UOM
 ,pr.Length_mm*pr.Width_mm*pr.Height_mm AS Volume_Cubic
 ,pr.Length_mm*pr.Width_mm AS Volume_Floor
 ,pr.Length_mm
 ,pr.Height_mm
 ,pr.Width_mm
FROM CostToServe_MCB.staging.Sale sa
    LEFT JOIN staging.Product pr ON sa.ID = pr.ID
where pr.Length_mm is not null and pr.Width_mm is not null and pr.Height_mm is not null
```

Comment: Sorry, the query I put up wasn't fully representative of the one I'm working with. It contains many other columns. The above answer limits the results on the 3 values.

Answer (score 0):

```
where pr.Length_mm is not null 
  and pr.Width_mm is not null 
  and pr.Height_mm is not NULL
```